spreadtab & odsfile : TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000]
I'm trying to use the package spreadtab to make a template for the \includespread command provided by the odsfile package (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/odsfile), but I get this error while compiling :

TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000].
@execute@begin@hook #1->
\UseHook {env/#1/begin}
l.28     \chiffrage{devis}{1}{2}

My ODS file looks like this, very basic :
A1  B1  C1  D1
A2  B2  C2  D2

Here is my code :
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{odsfile,booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\STsetdecimalsep{,}
\newcommand*\chiffrage[3]{%
    \tabletemplate{reclic}{%
        \setlength\LTleft{-1.5cm}
        \setlength\LTright{-3cm}
        \begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{1.15\textwidth}{-{coltypes}}}
            \toprule
            -{colheading}
            \midrule
            -{content}
            \midrule
            % @TOTAL & @\space & @\space & :={sum(d2:d#3)} € \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{spreadtab}
    }
    \includespread[columns=head,coltypes=Xrrr,template=reclic,file=#1.ods,sheet=#2,range=a:d#3]
}

\begin{document}
    Hey !

    \chiffrage{devis}{1}{2}
\end{document}

Do you have any idea what is causing this ? How can I solve this issue ?
Thanks in advance !

I get a different error from lua rather than tex: texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/odsfile/odsfile.lua:16: attempt to index a nil value (local 'f')
stack traceback:
...texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/odsfile/odsfile.lua:16: in function 'load'
[\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }
l.28     \chiffrage{devis}{1}{2}
?

Thanks as lot @DavidCarlisle for your interest !
I've seen this error but I can't see it in this minimal example... :-/ I'm using lualatex to compile (This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)).
But even with the error you get, I'm lost completely on how to get this working...
Thanks again and in advance for any help !

@DavidCarlisle this means that the ODS file you want to include doesn't exist. I guess I should have tested the existence of the file and give more useful error message :)

@michal.h21 I wondered if it meant that but I wasn't sure what the file is suppsoed to be called I guessesed devis.ods  as it mentions #1.ods in the code shown but I still get the Lua error.

I can confirm the error, but I am not sure if it can be fixed. It is possible that it is caused by the way how Spreadtab reads the content of the environment. I know that I recently dealt with a similar clash between Tabularx and Odsfile and it was something that couldn't be fixed.

@DavidCarlisle yes, it should be devis.ods. It works for me if I create such file in LibreOffice calc.

@michal.h21 "create in libre office" ah I have no idea what ods is I just saved exactly the text block in the question above as devis.ods is that the wrong thing?

@michal.h21 I see google sheets can save as ods I'll try that

I get the error now

Thanks a lot @michal.h21 for your answers !
I've written this code about two years ago and I think it has worked then (I can't really remember..., sorry) :-/
Thanks again for your interest.

@bricebou I've tried an older version of Odsfile from two years ago, and it fails as well. It is possible that the change happened in Spreadtab.

Thanks a lot @michal.h21 !
Yeah, maybe ; as the point is to have some kind of robust mechanism to import ods file, I'll try to stick with up to date versions of both odsfile and spreadtb. I'll look into alternative ways to achieve what I have in mind. I'm going to close this topic. Thanks again for your interest !

UNnfortunately, my problem may have no solution, as mentioned by @michal-h21 in the comments of the original post (spreadtab & odsfile : TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000]).
